# JQM later prepended flip switch doesn't react on events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I prepend this code:

```
        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="test">Test</label>
            <select class="marktplaatsenSwitch" id="test" data-role="slider" name="test">
                <option value="off">OFF</option>
                <option '+selected+'value="on">ON</option>
            </select>
        </li>
```

Inside of an ul with the id "settings"

And when I call this

```
    $( ".marktplaatsenSwitch" ).on( "change", function(event, ui) {
        alert("Test");
    });
```

It does not react on it. But it does work when I have the li already inside the ul. Do I need to do some kind of refresh? I already tried `listview("refresh")` and `selectMenu("refresh", true)`

Comment: Unclear what you are asking but sounds like you should delegate onchange event to closest static container http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use:

```
$( ".marktplaatsenSwitch" ).on( "change", function(event, ui) {
        alert("Test");
});
```

correct jQuery syntax is (if you want to access dynamically created event):

```
$(document).on( "change", ".marktplaatsenSwitch",function(event, ui) {
        alert("Test");
});
```

This way of event binding is called delegated binding, it doesnt card if element exist or don't exist inside the DOM.

Comment: Wow thanks this worked and I used the docuemnt function earlier but never knew what it exactly did. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Np I am glad to help.